# Facebook iOS SDK restarts the application

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad, single-sign-on

I want to publish scores of iPad game on Facebook when the game is over, game is made using cocos2d. I have made UIViewController and assigned it as delegate for FBConnect as well. I add it's subview on top of glView when i need to publish scores.But Facebook iOS SDK Single-Sign-On takes the application back to the first view of application when redirects after authorizing facebook app. I want it to simply remove this view from top view instead of going back to from where the application started. Is there any way to resume application from same point instead of restarting?

Also, how can we check if Facebook app is already authorized by a user so that application can skip authorization and can show "publish on wall" dialog start away?

Comment: I'm also after the same functionality. I don't want to have to authorise every time someone opens my app. Also clicking "Okay" every single time is just painful.

Comment: @Fulvio: I have added answer to question below. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Facebook lastest SDK's Single-sign on feature than the control gets out of your application. Solution is to leave SSO feature and make your custom class for Facebook connectivity. Implement login, publish and logout where you want and save access authorization in NSUSerDefaults. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170735/how-to-retrieve-facebook-response-using-facebook-iphone-sdk/5195951#5195951) post contains detail code to implement it. Hope it helps :)